# How do I null an array of pointers that is pointing to a Structure in C (not C++)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, null

I'm currently trying to Null an array of pointers that point to a structure. Any help or documentation would be nice. I am a beginner so please be as clear as possible.

Here is an example of my code. Sorry if I don't have this listed correctly, it's my first posting.enter code here

```
#include "stdlib.h"

enum boxtype
{
    Card,
        Mask,
};

typedef struct 
{
    enum boxtype type;
    int L;
    int H;
    int x;
    int y;
    int Area;
    Float ManBox;
    Float WomanBox;
}Boxes;

typedef struct
{
    Boxes Info;
    float Hight;
}Male;

typedef struct
{
    Boxes Info;
    int Size;
}Female;


void main()
{
    Man Male[100];
    Woman Female[100];
    Boxes *Spaces[600]; //This is the array of pointers that needs to be nulled.

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "nulling"? Initialise the array elements to null pointers? `Boxes *Spaces[600] = {0};` would do that. Oh, and **the return type of `main` shall be `int`**. Make it `int main(void)`.

Comment: It is `int main(void)`; the return value is an `int`.  What's wrong with `Boxes *Spaces[600] = { 0 };`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize an array with an initializer list like so:

```
Boxes *Spaces[600] = { NULL };
```

All of the elements in the array will be set to NULL.

Comment: this is wrong, it doesn't allocate 600 Boxes worth of memory and null them, it will segfault when you try to use the memory.

Comment: Correct, it will allocate an array of 600 pointers to type of Boxes and set them to NULL.

Edit: 600 NULL pointers: http://codepad.org/LnNOu2KD

Comment: +1: Looks fine to me; the compiler will initialize the array with nulls, whether it is function scope storage (as in the example) or file scope storage.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try this out and apply it to my code. I don't know yet if this is exactly what I want but thank you for your prompt accurate response.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood, I don't see the utility in this. if you need an array of pointers why would you statically allocate the memory for them, especially on the stack... makes a pretty big stack frame...

Answer (score 0):

if you initialize with `calloc()` the memory will be zero'ed before it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i=0;i<600;i++)
{
     *Space[i]=NULL;
}`
the previous given answer was also right. If u don't understand the previous code then u can try this one.